# Error: ! Font OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl/10.95=mathkerncmssi10 at 10.95pt not loadable: Met ric (TFM) file not found

Tags: beamer, compilation-error

I am encountering the following problem with Beamer. With the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Madrid}   
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \  
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amssymb, amstext, amsopn, amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts} % math enviornment
\usepackage{epsfig} %eps
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
```

Everything compiles greatly but when I add an equation environment, e.g.

```
\begin{equation}
a=2+b
\end{equation}
```

I get the following error message:

! Font OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl/10.95=mathkerncmssi10 at 10.95pt not loadable: Met
ric (TFM) file not found.
 
                   relax 
l.146 \end{frame}

The same happens when I use the math environment in between $ $.
Can somebody help?

I give here a brief example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Madrid}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amssymb, amstext, amsopn, amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts} % math enviornment
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$a$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The log file looks like the following:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(senza-nome-3.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamer.cls"
Document Class: beamer 2019/09/29 v3.57 A class for typesetting presentations

("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasem
odes.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.
sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbased
ecode.sty"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty"
))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaseo
ptions.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.st
y"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.
sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.
cfg"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size11.clo")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf
core.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.
sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.
sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
)
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graph
ics.cfg")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdfte
x.def")))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pg
fsys.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfr
cs.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pg
futil-common.tex"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pg
futil-common-lists.tex"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pg
futil-latex.def"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ms\everyshi.sty"))

("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pg
frcs.code.tex"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision
.tex")))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\
pgfsys.code.tex"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pg
fkeys.code.tex"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pg
fkeysfiltered.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\
pgf.cfg")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\
pgfsys-pdftex.def"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\
pgfsys-common-pdf.def")))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"

("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color
.cfg"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcore.code.tex"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
.code.tex"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
calc.code.tex"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
util.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
parser.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
functions.code.tex"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
functions.basic.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
functions.trigonometric.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
functions.random.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
functions.comparison.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
functions.base.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
functions.round.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
functions.misc.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
functions.integerarithmetics.code.tex")))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath
float.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.
code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorepoints.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorepathconstruct.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorepathusage.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorescopes.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcoregraphicstate.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcoretransformations.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorequick.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcoreobjects.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorepathprocessing.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorearrows.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcoreshade.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcoreimage.code.tex"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcoreexternal.code.tex"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorelayers.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcoretransparency.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorepatterns.code.tex")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\p
gfcorerdf.code.tex")))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\xxco
lor.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/atbegshi\atbegsh
i.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwar
err.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.
sty"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.
sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdftexcmds\pdftexc
mds.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetk
eys.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvd
efinekeys.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfesc
ape.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.st
y")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltx
macro.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.st
y")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoption
s.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.de
f")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.
sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmd
s.sty") ("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/url\url.st
y")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.st
y"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigin
tcalc.sty"))

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.d
ef"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/atveryend\atveryen
d.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rer
unfilecheck.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/uniquecounter\un
iquecounter.sty")))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaser
equires.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasec
ompatibility.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasef
ont.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.s
ty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.
sty"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/sansmathaccent\san
smathaccent.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfi
le.sty")))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaset
ranslator.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\transla
tor.sty"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasem
isc.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaset
woscreens.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaseo
verlay.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaset
itle.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbases
ection.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasef
rame.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasev
erbatim.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasef
ramesize.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasef
ramecomponents.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasec
olor.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasen
otes.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaset
oc.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaset
emplates.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasea
uxtemplates.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaseb
oxes.sty")))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasel
ocalstructure.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\enumerate.st
y"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbasen
avigation.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaset
heorems.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.st
y"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.

("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.st
y"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amscls\amsthm.sty"
))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerbaset
hemes.sty"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamertheme
default.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerfontt
hemedefault.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamercolor
themedefault.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerinner
themedefault.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerouter
themedefault.sty")))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamertheme
Madrid.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamercolor
themewhale.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamercolor
themeorchid.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerinner
themerounded.sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/beamer\beamerouter
themeinfolines.sty"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty"
)
No file senza-nome-3.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-p
df.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epsto
pdf-base.sty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/grfext\grfext.sty"
)) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.s
ty"
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.
sty")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\g
ettitlestring.sty"))
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\transla
tor-basic-dictionary-English.dict")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\transla
tor-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\transla
tor-environment-dictionary-English.dict")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\transla
tor-months-dictionary-English.dict")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\transla
tor-numbers-dictionary-English.dict")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/translator\transla
tor-theorem-dictionary-English.dict")
No file senza-nome-3.nav.
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd")

("C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/sansmathaccent\ot1
mathkerncmss.fd")Running miktex-makemf.exe...


Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.



The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:



  C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
Couldn't open `mathkerncmssi.cfg'



hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)




Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\bagna\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log

! Font OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl/10.95=mathkerncmssi10 at 10.95pt not loadable: Met
ric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.8 \end{frame}

?
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you make your example code compilable (add `\begin{document}`, a frame with the equation, and `\end{document}`, and remove all the packages that are not relevant for the problem? Also, can you compile a normal `article` document with math, or does it happen only in `beamer`? Which compiler do you use (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`)?

Comment: Which tex system are you using? Miktex? Did you check for updates and uninstalled packages in user and admin mode?

Comment: I have Miktex with TexWorks and also another versions of TexWorks than I installed it earlier alone which I do not use. I hope it is not giving issues (it never has so far). I use pdflatex as compiler. I can correctly compile ```article```, it happen only in ```beamer```. Example :

Comment: Yes it happens only with beamer as only beamer uses this font. You will have to install the sansmathaccent package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried to include sansmathaccent in the preamble, but it does not work

Comment: I wrote you should **install** the package. Go to the miktex console and learn how to use it to install missing packages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it's installed already

Comment: Then update it.

Comment: I already updated the package together with all the others in admin mode. But still, the same problem appears

Comment: It is missing an `\end{itemize}` at the first `\begin{frame}`. I run in a recent updated `MikTeX` Windows-PC, through `pdflatex` in `TeXstudio` and it worked without errors ... on the second run, the first created the `.aux` file and others.

Comment: Also, there is an extra `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` which leads to the MWE concept. Remove all non necessary packages to this issue. Believe me, I know it is somewhat painful because you want all of them to work together, but including more packages only make it difficult to find out the problem. I compiled your example only with the class `beamer`and with/without your selected theme , `Madrid`, an it worked fine.

Comment: @FHZ I tried by removing all the unnecessary packages. I still does not work and I get the same error

Comment: did you check for updates also in user mode?

Comment: yes, I tried both user and admin mode

Comment: Create a small complete example, then compile it and show the log-file.

Comment: I am also facing exact same problem. the problem is with math fonts and happens only in beamer. Any help would be nice.In fact the file which ran yesterday does not run today. Including align/equation for math equations creates this error.

Comment: I had the same problem after MikTeX update (for both experimental and update release variants) and Simon’s answer with `sansmathaccent` worked, but it seems more like a workaround than a solution. Probably `sansmathaccent` or some other package is affected or incompatible with another after the update. This only happens in Beamer and errors are triggered by, eg., using math mode, using `\url` command, or loading `siunitx` package.

Comment: An update to `sansmathaccent` has been released today which seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. I *uninstalled* sansmathaccent and clicked "no" when asked to install. Now compiles fine.

Comment: Finally! Your solution works!

Answer (score 5):

This is a packaging error in miktex. The sansmathaccent package is missing the tfm and vf files (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sansmathaccent/tfm, https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sansmathaccent/vf).

I made a bug report

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/162

The issue should be resolved fast.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit 2020-02-07:

**An update to `sansmathaccent` package is now available (version packaged on 2020-02-06) that solves the problem.**

Installing packages on the fly no longer interferes with using Beamer’s default math font.

---

Not a full answer, but a MWE demonstrating errors with console output and log excerpt as [requested in comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526790/error-font-ot1-mathkerncmss-m-sl-10-95-mathkerncmssi10-at-10-95pt-not-loadabl/527138?noredirect=1#comment1332371_526790).

Used most recent MiKTeX release on Windows 10 as of 2020-02-05T17:38:51Z.

As [mentioned by Simon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526979), uninstalling the `sansmathaccent` package and preventing MiKTeX from reinstalling it seems to serve as a workaround.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage{siunitx} % Triggers the error.

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        %\url{url} % Triggers the error.

        Text.

        $1+1$ % Triggers the error.

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Messages:

> ```
> Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Document".tex
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\‹username›\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
>
> Couldn't open `mathkerncmssi.cfg' hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)
>
> Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\‹username›\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\‹username›\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
>
> Couldn't open `mathkerncmss.cfg' hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)
>
> Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\‹username›\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\‹username›\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
>
> Couldn't open `mathkerncmss.cfg' hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)
>
> Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\‹username›\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log
>
> Process exited with errors
> ```

### Log (only parts relating to errors):

> ```
> …
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `pureletters' on input line 5.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `pureletters' in version `normal'
> (Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/it --> OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl on input line 5.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `pureletters' in version `bold'
> (Font)                  OT1/cmss/b/it --> OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl on input line 5.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `pureletters' in version `bold'
> (Font)                  OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl --> OT1/mathkerncmss/bx/sl on input line 5.
>
> …
>
> ("C:\Users\‹username›\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd"
> File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B)
> LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+mathkerncmss on input line 15.
>
> ("C:\Users\‹username›\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/sansmathaccent\ot1mathkerncmss.fd"
> File: ot1mathkerncmss.fd 2020/01/31 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/mathkerncmss.)
> ! Font OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl/10.95=mathkerncmssi10 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
> <to be read again> 
>                    relax 
> l.15  \end{frame}
>
> I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
> so I will ignore the font specification.
> [Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
> You might try inserting a different font spec;
> e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
>
> ! Font OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl/8=mathkerncmssi8 at 8.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
> <to be read again> 
>                    relax 
> l.15  \end{frame}
>
> I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
> so I will ignore the font specification.
> [Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
> You might try inserting a different font spec;
> e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
>
> ! Font OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl/6=mathkerncmssi8 at 6.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
> <to be read again> 
>                    relax 
> l.15  \end{frame}
>
> I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
> so I will ignore the font specification.
> [Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
> You might try inserting a different font spec;
> e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
>
> …
> ```

Comment: If it's not an answer, why post it as an answer?

Comment: To provide [an MWE and log requested in comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526790/error-font-ot1-mathkerncmss-m-sl-10-95-mathkerncmssi10-at-10-95pt-not-loadabl/527138?noredirect=1#comment1332371_526790) and make quick test easier for other users. I did’t want to edit the original question in lieu of the author.

Comment: That's not what answers are for; and indeed, that's precisely what editing questions is for.  Answers are only for answers to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. I included the package `newcent` with

```
\usepackage{newcent}
```

Now it is compiling well.

Comment: It works, but it give another font. I wanted the usual one for the math environment

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

add the above lines, is a "better" workaround in the meanwhile since don't require to stop installing (or uninstall) packages on the fly.