# Having issues with beamer. Error: Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed

Tags: beamer, miktex

I have been trying to compile a beamer presentation and have tried everything: reinstalling (MikTeX) and running updmap.exe etc... but to no avail. I keep getting this message. I will appreciate any help that I can get with this. Thanks!!.

### Error

> Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe... Couldn't open `mathkerncmss.cfg'
>
> hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)
>
> Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
>   again:
>
> C:\Users\axasma\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log
>
> ! Font OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl/6=mathkerncmssi8 at 6.0pt not loadable:
>   Metric (TF M) file not found.  
>                      relax  l.55 \begin{document}
>                         ?

---

### Log

```
> 2020-02-05 17:12:03,878-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm - starting with
> command line: miktex-maketfm --verbose mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05
> 17:12:03,903-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-makemf.exe...
> 2020-02-05 17:12:03,903-0500 INFO  maketfm - running:
> miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05 17:12:04,366-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
> 2020-02-05 17:12:04,366-0500 INFO  maketfm - running:
> miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance -g mathkerncmssi8 300 2020-02-05 17:12:04,721-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font
> mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:04,721-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No
> creation rule for font mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:04,721-0500
> FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info:  2020-02-05 17:12:04,721-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Source:  2020-02-05 17:12:04,721-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Line: 0 2020-02-05 17:12:05,129-0500 INFO 
> miktex-maketfm - starting with command line: miktex-maketfm --verbose
> mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05 17:12:05,154-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running
> miktex-makemf.exe... 2020-02-05 17:12:05,154-0500 INFO  maketfm -
> running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05 17:12:05,613-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
> 2020-02-05 17:12:05,613-0500 INFO  maketfm - running:
> miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance -g mathkerncmssi8 300 2020-02-05 17:12:05,962-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font
> mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:05,963-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No
> creation rule for font mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:05,963-0500
> FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info:  2020-02-05 17:12:05,963-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Source:  2020-02-05 17:12:05,963-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Line: 0 2020-02-05 17:12:06,414-0500 INFO 
> miktex-maketfm - starting with command line: miktex-maketfm --verbose
> mathkerncmssi12 2020-02-05 17:12:06,439-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running
> miktex-makemf.exe... 2020-02-05 17:12:06,439-0500 INFO  maketfm -
> running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose mathkerncmssi12 2020-02-05 17:12:06,894-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
> 2020-02-05 17:12:06,894-0500 INFO  maketfm - running:
> miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance -g mathkerncmssi12 300 2020-02-05 17:12:07,240-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font
> mathkerncmssi12. 2020-02-05 17:12:07,240-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm -
> No creation rule for font mathkerncmssi12. 2020-02-05
> 17:12:07,240-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info:  2020-02-05
> 17:12:07,241-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source:  2020-02-05
> 17:12:07,241-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 0 2020-02-05
> 17:12:07,664-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm - starting with command line:
> miktex-maketfm --verbose mathkerncmssi10 2020-02-05 17:12:07,688-0500
> INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-makemf.exe... 2020-02-05
> 17:12:07,689-0500 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-makemf.exe
> --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose mathkerncmssi10 2020-02-05 17:12:08,143-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running
> miktex-hbf2gf.exe... 2020-02-05 17:12:08,143-0500 INFO  maketfm -
> running: miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance -g mathkerncmssi10 300 2020-02-05 17:12:08,496-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font
> mathkerncmssi10. 2020-02-05 17:12:08,496-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm -
> No creation rule for font mathkerncmssi10. 2020-02-05
> 17:12:08,496-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info:  2020-02-05
> 17:12:08,496-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source:  2020-02-05
> 17:12:08,496-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 0 2020-02-05
> 17:12:08,903-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm - starting with command line:
> miktex-maketfm --verbose mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05 17:12:08,927-0500
> INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-makemf.exe... 2020-02-05
> 17:12:08,927-0500 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-makemf.exe
> --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05 17:12:09,380-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running
> miktex-hbf2gf.exe... 2020-02-05 17:12:09,380-0500 INFO  maketfm -
> running: miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance -g mathkerncmssi8 300 2020-02-05 17:12:09,735-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font
> mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:09,735-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No
> creation rule for font mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:09,735-0500
> FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info:  2020-02-05 17:12:09,735-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Source:  2020-02-05 17:12:09,735-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Line: 0 2020-02-05 17:12:10,187-0500 INFO 
> miktex-maketfm - starting with command line: miktex-maketfm --verbose
> mathkerncmssi10 2020-02-05 17:12:10,210-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running
> miktex-makemf.exe... 2020-02-05 17:12:10,210-0500 INFO  maketfm -
> running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose mathkerncmssi10 2020-02-05 17:12:10,675-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
> 2020-02-05 17:12:10,675-0500 INFO  maketfm - running:
> miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance -g mathkerncmssi10 300 2020-02-05 17:12:11,015-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font
> mathkerncmssi10. 2020-02-05 17:12:11,015-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm -
> No creation rule for font mathkerncmssi10. 2020-02-05
> 17:12:11,015-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info:  2020-02-05
> 17:12:11,015-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source:  2020-02-05
> 17:12:11,015-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 0 2020-02-05
> 17:12:11,428-0500 INFO  miktex-maketfm - starting with command line:
> miktex-maketfm --verbose mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05 17:12:11,453-0500
> INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-makemf.exe... 2020-02-05
> 17:12:11,453-0500 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-makemf.exe
> --miktex-enable-installer --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05 17:12:11,908-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running
> miktex-hbf2gf.exe... 2020-02-05 17:12:11,908-0500 INFO  maketfm -
> running: miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance -g mathkerncmssi8 300 2020-02-05 17:12:12,251-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font
> mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:12,252-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No
> creation rule for font mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:12,252-0500
> FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info:  2020-02-05 17:12:12,252-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Source:  2020-02-05 17:12:12,252-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Line: 0 2020-02-05 17:12:16,010-0500 INFO 
> miktex-maketfm - starting with command line: miktex-maketfm --verbose
> mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05 17:12:16,034-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running
> miktex-makemf.exe... 2020-02-05 17:12:16,035-0500 INFO  maketfm -
> running: miktex-makemf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance --verbose mathkerncmssi8 2020-02-05 17:12:16,487-0500 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...
> 2020-02-05 17:12:16,487-0500 INFO  maketfm - running:
> miktex-hbf2gf.exe --miktex-enable-installer
> --miktex-disable-maintenance -g mathkerncmssi8 300 2020-02-05 17:12:16,824-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No creation rule for font
> mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:16,824-0500 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No
> creation rule for font mathkerncmssi8. 2020-02-05 17:12:16,824-0500
> FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info:  2020-02-05 17:12:16,824-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Source:  2020-02-05 17:12:16,824-0500 FATAL
> miktex-maketfm - Line: 0
```

Comment: Is the sansmathaccent package installed?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes it is installed as \Uncategorized

Comment: I made a bug report: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a packaging error in miktex. The sansmathaccent package is missing the tfm and vf files (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sansmathaccent/tfm, https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/sansmathaccent/vf).

I made a bug report

https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/162

The issue should be resolved fast.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ulrike. I will wait for the updates.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem - after searching it I found the post [Error: ! Font OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl/10.95=mathkerncmssi10 at 10.95pt not loadable: Met ric (TFM) file not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526790/error-font-ot1-mathkerncmss-m-sl-10-95-mathkerncmssi10-at-10-95pt-not-loadabl) which I believe is the same issue, and gives the 2 solutions:

- Uninstalling the package sansmathaccent and clicking "no" when asked to install - this seems to work for some people, but didn't work for me.
- Including the package newcent - this makes it compile, but also changes the font which is undesirable.

Comment: I tried doing both the steps myself and the first one didn't work for me as well. The second one renders a different font so not useful for me.